# Nesting directives and using the data inside the local scope

Tags: angularjs, nested, directive, chart.js

So, I've been playing with Charts.js lately. What I'm trying to achieve is this : There's a number of charts that I want to draw. The number of charts depends on each user. It's a fitness app, I want to draw a chart for each type of exercise that a user has done.

Here's how I tried to do it :

1: Get each type of exercice that the user has done. That part is ok.

2: For each exercice, call a custom directive, give it the id of the exercice as an attribute.

```
<div ng-repeat="exercice in exercices">
    <exercice name="{{exercice.id}}"></exercice>
 </div>
```

So far, so good.

3: In my custom directive, get the exercice id, use it to retrieve the data in my database. Put the data into a local scope.

If I try to return

```
template : {{mydata}},
```

That works

4: In my custom directive, return a Chartjs directive that uses the data in step three to draw a chart. That's the part where I'm having troubles.

If I try to return

```
template : '<canvas data="mydata"></canvas>'
```

I've got an error, Chartjs can't find length of undefined. If I try to put double-brackets around mydata, it tells me there's an invalid key, etc.

So what I'm trying to do is to tell the Chartjs directive to use the data inside my custom directive, but I don't know if I'm on the right path. Any hint would be appreciated.

Here's a pastebin of my directive so far

http://pastebin.com/31apsmSP

Comment: Have you tried '<canvas data="'+{{mydata}}+'"></canvas>'

Comment: That's one of the first things that I tried. I keep getting the error "[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression …"

Comment: Could be solved by changing the local scope definition by replacing "@" with "=". "@" only supports one way binding strings and your directive is filling those parameters with an array, which is an object. So by changing this to "=" you achieve two things: The parameter actually can be an object (array) and value changes to those parameters are reflected in the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

With local scope parameters defined by "@" you only get one way binding of String values into the directive. There is no way back and such as the Arrays you set the scope variables to are only local to the directive. Plus @ only allows string values, no objects or arrays.

Instead define your directive like this (from your pastebin):

```
fitAdmin.directive('exercice', function(Client) {
  return {
    template: '<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="poidsExo" labels="exoLabel"></canvas> ',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      poidsExo: '=',
      exoLabel: '=',
  },
  link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

    Client.getClientResultsExercice(attrs.id, attrs.name).then (function (data) {
      scope.poidsExo = [];
      scope.exoLabel = [];
      var dateTemp;
      angular.forEach(data, function (data) {
        if (data.date !== dateTemp) {
          scope.poidsExo.push(data.poids);
          scope.exoLabel.push(data.date);
        dateTemp = data.date;
        };
      });
    })
  },

};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me. Right now I have another error.

_[$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'exercice' is non-assignable!_

I'm currently reading the documentation to understand the problem.

Comment: Did you check this? https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign  Try <exercice name="exercice.id"></exercice> without the double brackets.

Comment: It returns a 500 error, since Angular is trying to get results from http:/:myserver/myapi/exercice.id instead of an actual exercice ID.